# Why does docker run busybox timeout not work?

Tags: docker, busybox

I'm trying to make a script to quickly test whether the network connection works inside docker using busybox.

All of these tests failed to timeout after 5 seconds (they took 30 seconds to timeout):

```
docker run busybox wget -T 5 google.com
docker run busybox timeout 5 wget google.com
timeout 5 docker run busybox wget google.com
```

The only thing that worked was to shell into busybox interactively. That did successfully terminate in 5 seconds. But I'm trying to do this programmatically, not interactively.

```
docker run -it busybox

/ # timeout 5 wget google.com
Terminated
```

Why did the timeout work in the interactive shell, but does not work non-interactively?

I'm running from an Ubuntu 18:04 VM.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: using `-s9` to send SIGKILL.

`timeout -s9 5 docker run busybox wget google.com`